# Automatically switch to new rotated log

Tags: linux, logging

On debian I monitor nginx logs with tail command:

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

but since at midnight access.log is rotated (access.log is renamed as access.log.1 and new access.log is created), every day I have to stop the command and execute it again.

Is there a way to switch automatically to the new access.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `tail -F` option instead.

Comment: ```-F     same as --follow=name --retry``` Thank you!!